# How to edit video file in SharePoint online or add annotations and add comments in video SharePoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to edit video file in SharePoint online document library.I want to add annotations and comments in video file in SharePoint online document library.

Comment: Hi @Nirav Patel, please, could you be able to describe your use case in more detail? Maybe, you are searching for Stream app available in Office 365 as well as SharePoint Online. You are able to add webparts in classic and modern experiences to pages and redirect users to the Stream page for adding comments.

Comment: Hi @jaloplo,

Once i upload video in library then i want to add text in running video. if i can mark some part of video. once i upload video then it will go for next approval so approver can high light wrong thing of video.

Comment: I think you need [Stream](https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-stream) to do so. That's the platform for adding subtitles, face recognition and so much more things with videos.

Comment: @jaloplo Ok thank You so much, let me check with stream.